# How to set toast style as a theme?

Tags: android, toast, android-theme

I want to change all toasts in my App by editing `themes.xml`.

I am using `<item name="buttonStyle">@style/MyButton</item>` to change my buttons, is there something similar with Toasts, or do I have to create and use `MyToast` class which extends the built-in Toast?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can change the background of your Toast with this:

```
<style name="myTheme" parent="@android:styles/Theme.Holo">
  <item name="android:toastFrameBackground">@android:drawable/my_toast</item>
</style>
```

Comment: thank you Ahmad, is there any other customization rather than background? secondly is there a table for all item names such as `android:toastFrameBackground`

Comment: @bluebrain you can't set the gravity etc. with styles (as fas as I can tell), you'll have to do that programmatically. Android is open source, so you can find everything in here: https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/values/themes.xml

Comment: Can you change the background?  As another SO posts point out, toastFrameBackgound isn't public.  On API 18, I get an error saying no resource was found matching that name.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19215326/styles-toast-background-no-resource-found-that-matches-the-given-name

Comment: I cannot find `android:toastFrameBackground` in SDK 27.

Comment: This doesn't work for all devices, since "toastFrameBackground" isn't part of the public api {https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/values/public.xml}. The safe solution that works on all devices is just to use the `Toast.setView(view)`.

Answer (score -3):

Try this:

```
 Toast toast=new Toast(this);
     LayoutInflater inflater=this.getLayoutInflater();
     View toastView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.toast_layout, (ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.toastView));
     TextView txtDate=(TextView)toastView.findViewById(R.id.txtDate);
     txtDate.setText("toast appeared at "+Calendar.getInstance().getTime().toLocaleString());
     toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
     toast.setView(toastView);
     toast.show();
```

Comment: I don't see anything related to 'theme'(which is related to global, not a single toast) here, can you please elaborate the answer?